# state is not defined no - undef in react class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not able to locate any error here. please help!
My code is giving error when running npm install ,  if I use it with file generated with create-react-app. it is working fine. I don't know what dependencies and configuration are missing.I am getting the following error :

```
state is not defined no-undef
foo is not defined no-undef
```

My package.json is like this

```
 {
  "name": "processdesigner",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.8",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "i18next": "^19.8.4",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.0.1",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "^3.2.2",
    "mxgraph": "^4.2.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "radium": "^0.26.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-i18next": "^11.8.5",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0"
  }
}
```

And class component is this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component{
    state = {
       myState : "stateVal"
    };

    foo = () => {
        console.log("in foo");
    }

   render(){
      return (
         <></>
      );
   }

}
```

Comment: You would need @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react

Answer (score 0):

Also got the same issue today.

Looks like one of dependencies of package `react-scripts` causing that issue - `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` has been updated to version 4.15.2 (or maybe one of it's dependencies has been updated, not sure exactly).

Anyways, solution was to update `package.json` and add this line:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "<4.15.2",
    ...
  }
}
```

Then I deleted folder `node_modules` completely and run `yarn install` and `yarn build`. Or you will need to run `npm install` and `npm build`, depending on your project.

Hopefully, it helps also for you.